# Getting tkinter labels to update when variable changes

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to build an app with pythons tkinter module.

Currently I'm trying to get a labels displayed text to change when a radiobutton is selected. I have the labels text set to a textvariable, and a function which changes the textvariable to the required text depending on which button is selected. However, I'm expecting the Labels text to change since it's governing textvariable has changed. However is doesn't update.

Any help to get it updating will be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
info = Label(mainwindow, bg = 'magenta', height = 10, width = 40, text = weatherinfo, font = ('arial', 14, 'normal'))
info.pack(side = LEFT,padx = 20)

weatherinfo = 'select your city'
```

Then my check function changes weatherinfo

```
weatherinfo = '\n'.join([z, y, x, w, v, u,t])
print weatherinfo
```

The correct values print out on the shell but the original info label doesnt update and remains displaying 'select your city'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, `Label` updates every click of `Radiobutton` using command option of `Radiobutton` and `Label`'s text variable.

```
from Tkinter import *

def radio_action():
    value1 = var1.get()
    changeable_label['text'] = value1

the_window = Tk()
the_window.title('Example')

the_window.geometry("200x150")

var1 = StringVar()

changeable_label = Label(the_window, text = "Null")
button1 = Radiobutton(the_window, text = 'Button1', variable = var1,
                     value="Something", command = radio_action)

changeable_label.pack(side = TOP)
button1.pack()


the_window.mainloop()
```

Since I don't know your whole code, this is I can help with an example.

Comment: Thanks mate got it working, cant show all my code because its 550 lines